# call php function in button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to call the PHP function when I click the button in html page.

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function() {

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "hello.php",
    }).done(function(  ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: ");
    });    
});

});
</script>

<input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Buy!" />
```

Hello.php:

```
   <?php
   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
   {
      counterminus();
   }
   function  counterminus()
   {
      echo "method called";
   }
```

I have tried the above method but its not working properly.I need to print the string in the  counterminus() method when i click the button.

Comment: you miss <form action="hello.php"><input type="submit" name="submit"  id="submit" value="Buy!" /></form>tag

Comment: php is a `server side` `language` not a `client side` language like `javascript` you can't call a php function in `button click event` .. but yes you can use ajax to call a php file with your function...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#submit').click(function() {

 var val = $('#submit').val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
data:"var="+val,
url: "hello.php",
}).done(function(  ) {
alert( "Data Saved: ");
});
```

});

});

the above script will POST the variable name var with the value of the submit to hello.php

on hello.php

```
 echo $_POST['var'];
```

will result in "buy!"

so

```
  if(isset($_POST['var'])){
  .....
  .....
```

Comment: I don't think this will help, but you should explain your logic.

Comment: my thought is there is no form brackets/data so im not sure the submit actually gets sent.  Adding the data string will make sure something gets sent to hello.php

Comment: how to pass the action in data

Comment: what do you mean "pass the action"?  the click event listens for the click of the submit button, when it does it fires off the ajax call.

Comment: no i mean how to pass the variable,so that i can print that variable value inside php function

Comment: lol, an accepted answer with a -1.  there should be a badge for that.

Comment: hi please tell me how pass more than three variables in ajax

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks fine to me, except that you do not print the data returned by your AJAX call, which shall be provided as a parameter to your `done` callback.

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "hello.php",
}).done(function(data) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if by any case you put the input type="submit"  button inside a form tag. you should stop the event from executing.. put this at your ajax call. Because the form will post before the ajax call completes.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#submit').click(function(e) {
               e.preventDefault();
               $.ajax({
                     type: "POST",
                     url: "hello.php",
                      }).done(function(  ) {
                             alert( "Data Saved: ");
                                });    
         });

         });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

pass a variable submit with url

try the following code

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "1.php?submit=",
        }).done(function( data ) {
        alert( "Data Saved: "+data);
        });
```

or u can pass values as data

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "1.php",
            data: {submit:""},
            }).done(function( data ) {
            alert( "Data Saved: "+data);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use exit in php. now it returns "method called" string

```
   if(isset($_REQUEST['submit']))
   {
      counterminus();
   }
   function  counterminus()
   {
      echo "method called";
      exit;
   }
```